# How to get Principal Id in app service using Arm template?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

Hi I am writing ARM templates to deploy my app service. I want to create system identity in my arm template. In app service arm template section I have below code.

```
"identity": {
                "principalId": "[reference(variables('identity_resource_id'), '2017-12-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
                "tenantId": "[parameters('tenantId')]",
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            }
```

Then in variable section I added

```
"appServiceNameFrontEnd": "[concat(variables('defaultConvention'),'03-','FrontEnd')]"
"identity_resource_id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('appServiceNameFrontEnd')), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default')]"
```

Whenever I tried to run this I get below error

> ##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'FrontEnd' at line '1' and column '10436' is not valid: The template
> function 'reference' is not expected at this location. Please see
> https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details..

Can someone help me how can I get system assigned identity? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't specify the id for the system-assigned identity.
The valid template is:

```
"identity": {
    "type": "SystemAssigned"
}
```

The tenantId will be the tenant linked to the subscription always.
If you need that elsewhere, you can use `[subscription().tenantId]`.
To access the objectId of the system-assigned identity elsewhere, you can use e.g.:

```
"objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('appServiceNameFrontEnd')), '2016-08-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
```

(do remember to specify the App Service as a dependency on the resource so that it is only deployed once the App Service has been deployed)